# Invoke PropertyEditor from OpenToolsAPI

Tags: delphi, shortcut, invoke, propertyeditor

I need to invoke a PropertyEditor when I use a ShortCut created via OTA, or click on a MenuItem.

For example: I need to open a Form for a Hint property. This works when I click on the Hint property, but I need to use the same behaviour using a Shortcut created via OTA, or clicking on a MenuItem  created via a ComponentEditor.

It is possible?

Comment: You need to show your code - readers will not waste thei time guessing what it might be.

Comment: PropertyEditors are not intended to be invoked programmably by components or other editors. Why do you need this?

Comment: I'm using a PropertyEditor to show a Form Expert that can create Componentes and change properties from created components. This occurs in Design-Time and I use OTA to manipulate objects inside project. I can call this form Expert to do this task, but I don't have access to Designer, PropInfo, etc to create this components.

Comment: I use a PropertyEditor to call a Form Expert in order to configure some properties and create components at design-time. This work great, but I need to do this using menu item, Context menu or shortcut to call this same Form Expert and access the same property and form Designer, PropInfo, etc. How can I do that?